# When passing data how can I make a variable recognizable to multiple classes?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that passes in a string to determine what class my destination `vc` will be once I navigate. I'm also passing data to `vc` regardless of which class `vc` ends up being cast as. However, I'm getting an expected error of

> VAlue of type 'UIViewController?' has no member ....

since `vc` hasn't been cast as any subclass yet.

```
func passAndNavigateResultsFor(surveyName: String){

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()

    //Determining which class vc will be cast as

    if surveyName == "EFDizzinessSurveyTask" {
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :surveyName) as! EFDizzinessSurveyResults
    } else if surveyName == "EFHipArthritisSurveyTask" {
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :surveyName) as! EFHipArthritisSurveyResults
    } else if surveyName == "EFKoosKneeSurveyTask" {
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :surveyName) as! EFKoosKneeSurveyResults
    } else if surveyName == "EFLEFSSurveyTask" {
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :surveyName) as! EFLEFSSurveyResults
    } else if surveyName == "EFQuickDASHSurveyTask" {
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :surveyName) as! EFQuickDASHSurveyResults
    } else if surveyName == "EFNeckDisabilitySurveyTask" {
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :surveyName) as! EFNeckDisabilitySurveyResults
    }

    //Data that I want to pass through regardless of which class vc is cast as

    if (firstNameResult != nil) && (lastNameResult != nil) {
        self.fullName = self.firstNameResult! + " " + self.lastNameResult!
        vc.nameText = self.fullName!
    }
    if painLevelResult != nil {
        vc.painLevelText = String(describing: painLevelResult!)
    }
    if careSatisfactionResult != nil {
        vc.careSatisfactionText = String(describing: careSatisfactionResult!)
    }
    if rateProgressResult != nil {
        vc.rateProgressText = String(describing: rateProgressResult!)
    }
    if therapyGoalsResult != nil {
        vc.therapyGoalsText = String(describing: therapyGoalsResult!)
    }
    if step1Result != nil {
        vc.step1Text = String(describing: step1Result!)
    }
    if step2Result != nil {
        vc.step2Text = String(describing: step2Result!)
    }
    if step3Result != nil {
        vc.step3Text = String(describing: step3Result!)
    }
    if step4Result != nil {
        vc.step4Text = String(describing: step4Result!)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix this problem, or should I look at a solution like `prepareForSegue` instead?

Comment: If **all** view controllers contain **all** properties like `painLevelText` and `step2Text` create a base class declaring all properties and make your `....Results` classes subclasses of this base class. Consider that all instantiated controllers in the `if - else if` chain will never be used. You should get a warning about that.

Comment: +1 to @vadian comment. Why do you think `prepareForSegue` would work? It's equivalent to coding a push/pop (actually only a pop) to the VC stack. If you want VC #3 to get a variable that is passed between VC #1 and VC #2, that won't do it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact error being thrown? What member does it not exactly have?

Personally I agree with you and would use prepare for segue like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let yourVC = segue.destination as? YourViewController {
        yourVC.painLevelText = painLevelText
    }
}
```

You could find, cast, and prepare the correct VC in there.

If you are having problems with properties not found then you should consider creating a superclass for your VC's to store properties like `painLevelText`

Comment: @dfd the code looks like OP is trying to assign the type of ViewController at instantiation and then access a property. Prepare for segue offers a better solution  **instead of accessing the properties after instantiation**. I cannot confirm if those properties were already created but I included it for clarification, thanks